# Why i cannot import pygame?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame

I have this error when I try to import the pygame module all I did was import Pygame my operating system is Linux Ubuntu 14.04 with python 3.6.9 installed.I think the version i'm running but it's difficult for me to change it, this is the error.

```
import pygame ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pygame'
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/206009/discussion-on-question-by-pythonfan-why-i-cannot-import-pygame).

Answer (score 1):

`python` refers to `Python2`, so to install it run `python3 -m pip install -U pygame --user` and execute your script using `python3 yourscript.py`.

**Make sure everything is done through `python3` and `pip3`!** Maybe you want to [create an alias](https://askubuntu.com/questions/320996/how-to-make-python-program-command-execute-python-3).

Comment: Better would be to create a virtualenv with python3 as the default. Then python and pip symbols get aliased for you, and your pygame install will not contaminate your system environment, just your local virtualenv